# $U(1)$ bundles over a flat Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^d$ or Minkowski $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$ space

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, vector-bundles, gauge-theory

I know that we can have a $U(1)$ bundle over the base manifold like $S^2$. For example, we can choose the fibre $U(1)=S^1$ over $S^2$ as the $S^3$ Hopf fibration.

Now, can we have any nontrivial $U(1)$ bundles over a flat Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^d$ or Minkowski $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$ space?

If so, could you give some examples?

If not, could you give me a proof? (or at least sketch your arguments to convince me?)

Comment: The base is contractible, so if you're asking about smooth bundles they're all trivial. (Flatness of the base is immaterial.)

Comment: How about Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$? Can there be nontrivial bundles over a flat space $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$ with metric $(+++++...+-)?

Comment: How about Minkowski space ℝ$^{,1}$? Can there be nontrivial bundles over a flat space ℝ,1 with metric (+++++...+-)?